# How to select IDs with colons using Nokogiri?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

Someone decided it'd be awesome to use a colon in all their ID names, so now I'm stuck trying to select those ID names.

I'm using Nokogiri and I need to select an item with the ID of `tapListResultForm:resDetail_pg_3`.

As in: `<span id="tapListResultForm:resDetail_pg_3">Example</span>`

I've tried this:

```
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
doc.css('#tapListResultForm:resDetail_pg_3')
```

But that throws a RuntimeError: `RuntimeError: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function resDetail_pg_3 not found`

Comment: can you do this? doc.css('#tapListResultForm\:resDetail_pg_3')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
doc.css("span[@id='tapListResultForm:resDetail_pg_3']")
```